# Postgresql - Tentando um rollback numa função

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, funções

A estrutura de relação entre tabelas apresentada abaixo não é das mais convenientes e técnicas.
Serve apenas para ilustrar o que preciso.

Já li bastantes artigos sobre function, trigger functions e estou com um problema, porque em nenuma parte eu consegui uma resposta: preciso fazer um update em duas tabelas diferentes no mesmo procedimento e verificar se a segunda tabela tem consistência com a primeira.

Explico:

a) tenho uma tabela (tabfaturas) que guarda faturas emitidas e que tem um campo para o 'número da fatura', um outro para o 'volume financeiro' dos pedidos que fazem parte uma fatura e outro para indicar o 'status' de faturas pendentes ou pagas.

b) tenho outra tabela que guarda uma referência aos pedidos (tabpedidos) constantes na tabela anterior, que tem os campos 'número da fatura'  e 'status' de pedidos que fazem parte de uma fatura paga ou não. 
A referência entre as duas tabelas é o 'número da fatura', que não são índices por natureza.

c) Por fim, caso haja a 'baixa' na tabfatura por pagamento, preciso sinalizar em tabpedidos o status de pagos.

Preciso me certificar que todos os registros da tabela tabpedidos serão baixados se houver baixa na tabfaturas, trocando em ambas o código do campo status para 'baixado'.

Mas, não posso permitir que a soma dos pedidos ligados a uma determinada fatura não 'bata' com o valor assinalado na tabfaturas, caso inadvertidamente alguém possa ter 'mexido' na tabpedidos por um motivo qualquer.

Eu usaria, para isto, uma função escrita em plpgsql.

Entretanto, pelo que entendi, não posso usar ROLLBACK dentro de função e nem SAVEPOINT, caso, por um motivo qualquer, o 'volume financeiro' dos pedidos assinalados na tabela tabfaturas não corresponda ao somatório dos valores dos pedidos.

Isto é, se os valores divergirem, o update da tabfaturas precisa ser anulado.

Existe um 'rollback' ou terei de fazer, dentro da função, uma estrutura IF THEN ELSE para testar valores antes do update?

Comment: Somente a partir da versão 11 foi implementado o suporte a transações embutidas em linguagens server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Segundo esse post do SO (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12778209/are-postgresql-functions-transactional), as funções herdam o comportamento da transação em que foram chamados.

Se a chamada da função estiver numa transação, a função se comporta adequadamente. Então, para tudo funcionar como esperado, você só precisa garantir que a função seja chamada em uma transação, seja via SQL, seja por algum outro programa que gere a query SQL e envie para o banco de dados.